# Unexpected symbol(s) found:"html" error is showed in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I use `*html` (in CSS files) before class names for IE6 fixes. But Netbeans shows such `*html` as errors. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Good question, actually. I wouldn't be surprised if NetBeans doesn't allow to disable syntax checking...

Answer (score 2):

`*html` is not a valid selector.

Using the `* html` selector is [one way to target IE6 and below](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#in_css-selectors). The reason that it's called a hack is because they aren't any elements above the `html` tag: the `html` tag is the root of the DOM tree (except for `document`, but CSS can't target that). The `* html` selector implies that the `html` tag could be a descendant of something, but, being the root, it can't be.

**edit**: Wikipedia also has a [nice explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_HTML_hack) of this selector.

Comment: Hey thanks Alex. So, its obvious that it shows error in that particular line. Can I avoid that particular error in Netbeans(somewhere in exceptions)?